# How to use CHAR_LENGTH() in CREATE TABLE query - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My question may sound vague but am going to try as much as possible to make it clear enough. Prior to this, I have made some research on the internet and other SO pages but to no avail.
Is it possible to use `CHAR_LENGTH()` function in a `CREATE TABLE` clause like we usually do in `SELECT` Clause :

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH("SQL Tutorial") AS LengthOfString;
```

What I want to do is similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `no_of_chars` int(4) NULL DEFAULT CHAR_LENGTH(`content`) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

But the above `CREATE` statement gives an error near `CHAR_LENGTH`.
Precisely, During insertion of a record into such a table, I want the server to be able to read the length of the `content` field and store in `no_of_chars` field as default value.

**Is this POSSIBLE?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could use generated column:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `no_of_chars` int(4) AS ( CHAR_LENGTH(`content`)) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f836514e5b7e8b65df8dc526ee38860f)**

Comment: Exactly what am looking for, it works pretty well too when the record is updated.